# Javascript: Getting the width of child-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I have two stacked divs.

The outer div has a fixed width with overflow hidden.

The inner div has content that in total can be larger than the outher div.

How can I get the total width of the content of the inner div?

```
<div id='outer' style='width:100px'>
    <div id='inner'>
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try *$('#inner').width()* and the content is larger than outer, it will return the width of the outer div.

I am using Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/4syEJ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `.scrollWidth` of the parent, which will return what you want.

`document.getElementById('outer').scrollWidth`

http://jsfiddle.net/4syEJ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
<div id="outer" style="width:100px">
    <div id="inner">
        <p id="content">content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
$('#content').width();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.children()` jquery selector like this:

```
$('#info').html($('#box1').children().width(); 
$('#box2').children().width(); 
$('#box3').width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4syEJ/2/

Comment: Thanks, works fine. But I have the feeling Nicks solution is more performant.

Comment: your http://jsfiddle.net/4syEJ/4/ shows 200/250/250 for me. what browser are you using?